# how can I delegate a call passing through the block that came with it?

Tags: ruby, block, delegation, proc-object

I'm traversing an object graph and want to pass it a block that will run on each node of the structure from a method - let's called **visit**.

At the top, I'm going to call with a block and I want to delegate the initial call to visit on the root object to visit on other objects. **I can unpack the block into a proc locally using &last_parameter_name - but how do I turn the proc back into a block on my delegated call?**

Here's a simplified example where I call **first(...)** and want to delegate the block through to my call to **second(...)**

```
def second(&block)   # ... ? ...
  block.call(72)
end

def first(&block)
  puts block.class     # okay - now I have the Proc version
  puts 'pre-doit'
  block.call(42)
  puts 'post-doit'
  second( ... ? ...)   # how do I pass the block through here?
end

first {|x| puts x*x}
```

Note: I need to have the same conventions on first() and second() here - i.e. they need to take the same things.

**Having read and tried the answers, I've come up with a fuller, working example:**

```
class X 
  def visit(&x)
    x.call(50)
  end
end

class Y < X
  def visit(&x)
    x.call(100)
    X.new.visit(&x)
  end
 end

Y.new.visit {|x| puts x*x}
```

Comment: I know it's only an example, but if you have `puts` in the block, you don't need double the `puts` inside `def second...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then as simply as

```
second &block
```

Comment: @pgmura, no, it's ok in ruby 1.9.2

Comment: Tried both in 1.9.1 and 1.8.7, works with `&`, doesn't work without.

Comment: It didn't work for me in 1.8.6 but it did on 1.8.7 and 1.9. It's nice to know

Answer (score 3):

This explicit passing around of blocks is not always necessary if you use *yield*.

```
def first( &block )
  puts block.class     # okay - now I have the Proc version
  puts 'pre-doit'
  yield 42
  puts 'post-doit'
  second( &block ) #the only reason the &block argument is needed. yield 42 can do without.
end

def second #no block argument here, works all the same 
  yield 72
end

first {|x| puts x*x}
```

Comment: Another "trick" I learned just now: if you don't explicitly assign a block to a variable using `def first(&block)` syntax above, you can do it later using `block = Proc.new`. With no parameters, `Proc.new` takes a given block, converts it to a `Proc` and returns it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call second and pass it the block variable (in this case a Proc).

```
second block
```